# TextInput cannot capture the whole content again after delete part of the string

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

I have a TextInput textInputA with id textInputId in my application. When I type some words in it, I can get the whole string by using textInputId.text~~
However, when I delete part of the words and type some new words in the end of the string, textInputId.text cannot capture the new words added.

My task is if the words input contain a dot "." , a warning should pop up
The guarding works every time when I type in new word, but fail when I delete part of the words and type new words again

Can someone kindly give me some insight?
Thank you very much!

```
private function textChange(event:Event):void{

if(txtPymtMethDtlTxnDesc.text.indexOf(".") >= 0 ){

outerDocument.model.showRestrictDotInputWarning();

    }

}

<mx:TextInput change="textChanged(event);"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the string from the event (event.currentTarget.text) instead ?

Comment: You may also try 'textInput' event instead of 'change'.